# Непонятный отступ в HTML

Tags: html, css

Вроде везде отключил *margin* и *padding*, но всё равно вокруг главного блока `.intro` появляются белые линии:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height:1.6;
  color: #333;
}

html{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,*:after, *:before{
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
  margin: 0;
}

/*container*/
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/*intro*/

.intro {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;

  background: url(../images/intro.jpg) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kaushan+Script&family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kaushan+Script&family=Montserrat:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Mogo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="intro"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Mogo</h1>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/Em-An/pen/jVjbLM вот здесь подсмотрите что и как

Answer (score 3):

Инспектор Вам в помощь. Жмете «CTRL SHIFT C», а дальше водите курсором по странице в поисках элементов с отступами. Но, скорее всего, просто не отключили у body.

```
html, body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```